# Substitute indexes with names in a series of lines containing vectors of indexes

Tags: vim

I have a file that consists of two parts (Items & Vectors) like so :

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
Seven
Eight
Nine

Vectors
-------
[1,1,4,1]
[6,3,9,8,2]
[5,7,7,4,6,6]
```

I would like to modify Vectors section like so :

```
Vectors
-------
[One,One,Four,One]
[Six,Three,Nine,Eight,Two]
[Five,Seven,Seven,Four,Six,Six]
```

I want to do it exclusively in Vim.

**Is there a way that would substitute indexes automatically ?**

An index represents the line number where the item is defined.

I have made a few attempts mixing :s command with \=line() function to retrieve the item but went nowhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can with just a dash of Vim script.

```
:s/\v\d+/\=getline(str2nr(submatch(0)))/g
```

That is,

- `:s`ubstitute
- any sequence of digits `\v\d+`
- with the value of the expression `getline(str2nr(submatch(0)))` (take the whole match, transform it into a number, then get the contents of the corresponding line),
- and do so exhaustively for all matches in the line `g`.

Use Visual mode to apply the substitution command to your 'Vectors' section:

```
:'<,'>s/\v\d+/\=getline(str2nr(submatch(0)))/g
```

Comment: I like the clever using `getline()` to get the line's value

Comment: I am sorry for asking but why is `str2nr()` necessary? It works for me even like `:s/\v\d+/\=getline(submatch(0))/g`.

Comment: @ryuichiro In this particular case `str2nr()` isn't strictly necessary (since the regex matches only digits), but that's the exception rather than the norm.  `submatch()` always returns strings, and according to the manual: _When {lnum} is a String that doesn't start with a digit, line() is called to translate the String into a Number._ See `:help line()` to see what `line()` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substitute sub-replace expression.

First create a dictionary of your key/value pairs:

```
let dict = { '1': 'One', '2': 'Two', '3': 'Three', '4': 'Four', '5': 'Five', '6': 'Six', '7': 'Seven', '8': 'Eight', '9': 'Nine'}
```

Now run the substitution on the body of text:

```
%s/\d/\=get(dict, submatch(0), submatch(0))/g
```

The sub replace expression will look up the value of the dictionary, `dict`, via the `get()` function using the match, `submatch(0)`.

For more help see:

```
:h sub-replace-expression
:h get(
:h dict
```